# How exactly compile sqllite app in Code Blocs on Windows in c++

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, codeblocks

(My first question)
I have no idea how i can compile and link my project in Code Blocs on Windows in c++ properly. I included  and i set up it's localization in compiler options. I assume that i need to link any library. I read that it can by sqlite(3?).lib but in all downloadable files on sqlite project site is only .dll

huge thx for help

Comment: sorry [..]  I included sqlite3.h and i set up it's localization in compiler options [...]

Comment: Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way of using the SQLite library is to embed it directly in your application, i.e., download [the amalgamation source code](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), and just add the sqlite3.c and .h files to your project in the sample place where you have the other source files.

Also [how build sqlite lib](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) , [how to use def files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx)